# Spring data Cassandra API code samples

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

Is there any place where we can find code samples for different features (at least for most used methods) of CassandraTemplate ?

Answer (score 0):

The best place I know is the source code, here: [CassandraOperations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraOperations.java) is the code for the interface.

You can also look up its test classes to see the methods in action.